Can prematurely commenting on motive harm a prosecution?
Can premature statements about a crime being a hate crime harm a prosecution?
If so, does it matter if the statements are made by a politician or the police, and would it extend towards only explicit statements about an accused’s motive, or would it also extend towards generalised condemnation of a certain bigotry or noting that a victim was in a minority group on their way to engage in worship?
In case specifics matter, assume the prejudice was antisemitism (presumably as a religion rather than a race) and the alleged crime occurred in Chicago, Illinois, USA.

Prematurely communicating any type of fact of an investigation has the potential to harm an investigation or prosecution. There is no category of fact that is universally "safe" to communicate without prejudice to an ongoing investigation.
Of course, in any given case, there may be facts where communicating them would present a low risk to the investigation.
If it is premature to communicate a fact, police and prosecution will avoid communicating it.
This has been recognized many times by privacy commissions and courts in Canada:

public access to investigative files would do much to frustrate the conduct of investigations, and premature disclosures prior to trial would impair the ability of the prosecution to effectively present its case


it is desirable in the public interest that police investigations be kept confidential to prevent premature disclosure to potential accused of the nature and extent of the evidence as of that date.

To avoid premature disclosure, disclosure of information to the suspect, other involved individuals, or to the public usually will only happen after weighing the risks to the investigation against the need for the disclosure to advance the investigation.
Eventually, there is also a point where disclosure to the accused is mandatory: many critical details are required in the indictment, and then the accused is owed full disclosure of all relevant evidence in the hands of the prosecution and police.

Could you give some examples of how a premature disclosure could cause harm, and how the authorities would decide when it's "mature" enough?
